# A closed form for $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(-\ln x)\ \operatorname{li}^2x}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, logarithms, closed-form

Let $\operatorname{li}x$ denote the logarithmic integral [$^{[1]}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html)[$^{[2]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function)[$^{[3]}$](http://web.archive.org/web/20130524225414/http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2):
$$\operatorname{li}x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{\ln t}$$
and
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(-\ln x)\ \operatorname{li}^2x}{x}dx\approx-4.311872263...$$
Is it possible to express the integral $I$ in a closed form (using algebraic numbers, known mathematical constants, elementary and known special functions)?

Comment: http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will start from Vladimir's result and [my calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514256/conjectural-closed-form-for-int-0-infty-sqrt3z-operatornameei2-z-dz/514311#514311). Let

$$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} z^{s-1} \mathrm{Ei}(-z)^{2} \, dz = \frac{2\Gamma(s)}{s} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{u^{s-1}}{1 - u} \, du. $$

Then we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} z^{s-1} \mathrm{Ei}(-z)^{2} \log z \, dz
&= F'(s) \\
&= F(s) \left( \psi_{0}(s) - \frac{1}{s} \right) + \frac{2\Gamma(s)}{s} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{u^{s-1}\log u}{1-u} \, du.
\end{align*}

Plugging $s = 1$ to both sides,

\begin{align*}
I
&= F(1) \left( \psi_{0}(1) - 1 \right) + 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\log u}{1-u} \, du \\
&= -2(\gamma+1)\log 2 + 2 \left[ \mathrm{Li}_{2}(1-u) \right]_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= -\zeta(2) - \log^{2} 2 - 2(\gamma + 1) \log 2
\end{align*}

as desired. Here,

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Li}_{2}(z) = - \int_{0}^{z} \frac{\log(1 - t)}{t} \, dt
\end{align*}

is the dilogarithm and we exploited the special values

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Li}_{2}(1) &= \zeta(2), \\
\mathrm{Li}_{2}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right) &= \frac{1}{2}\zeta(2) - \frac{1}{2}\log^{2} 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 14):

Change the integration variable $z=\ln x$, then apply the [formula $(12)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html). The integral becomes
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^0\ln(-z)\,\operatorname{Ei}^2z\ dz,\tag1$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}z$ is the [exponential integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html):
$$\operatorname{Ei}z=-\int_{-z}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}t dt.\tag2$$

In this form the integral can be evaluated by [*Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica):
$$I=-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\ln^2 2-2\,(1+\gamma)\ln2,\tag3$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html).